# Does this use 256-bit AES encryption?

Tags: java, encryption, jce

I think it's hashing a 256 bit key, not sure if this is producing 256 bit cipher text though. Does using a 256-bit key mean the cipher will produce a 256-bit cipher text? The resultant cipher text is base 64 encoded.

Thanks!

```
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

import com.ibm.broker.javacompute.Base64;

public class Security {
    private static final String AES_PASS = "43qyu3qwjaw8ga5azbro00ig"; // Hashed into an AES key later
    private SecretKeySpec keyObj;
    private Cipher cipher;
    private IvParameterSpec ivObj;

    public Security() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        // A constant IV, since CBC requires an IV but we don't really need one
        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        this.ivObj = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        // Create an SHA-256 256-bit hash of the key
        byte[] key = AES_PASS.getBytes();
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32); // Use only first 256 bit
        this.keyObj = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        // Create a Cipher by specifying the following parameters
        //  a. Algorithm name - here it is AES 
        //  b. Mode - here it is CBC mode 
        //  c. Padding - e.g. PKCS7 or PKCS5
        this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    }

    public String encrypt(String strDataToEncrypt) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        String strCipherText = new String();

        this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.keyObj, this.ivObj);

        // Encrypt the Data 
        //  a. Declare / Initialize the Data. Here the data is of type String 
        //  b. Convert the Input Text to Bytes 
        //  c. Encrypt the bytes using doFinal method
        byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = strDataToEncrypt.getBytes();

        byte[] byteCipherText = this.cipher.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt);

        // b64 is done differently on Android
        strCipherText = Base64.encode(byteCipherText);

        return strCipherText;
    }

    public String decrypt(String strCipherText) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        String strDecryptedText = new String();

        // Initialize the Cipher for Encryption
        this.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.keyObj, this.ivObj);

        // Decode the Base64 text
        byte[] cipherBytes = Base64.decode(strCipherText);

        // Decrypt the Data
        //  a. Initialize a new instance of Cipher for Decryption (normally don't reuse the same object)
        //     Be sure to obtain the same IV bytes for CBC mode.
        //  b. Decrypt the cipher bytes using doFinal method
        byte[] byteDecryptedText = this.cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
        strDecryptedText = new String(byteDecryptedText);

        return strDecryptedText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example appears to use a 32-byte key and a 256 bit version of the AES cryptosystem. So, technically yes it is 256-bit AES encryption. The actual size of the message determines the resulting output but it should be larger then the original message. Also, you should be able to decrypt it and get the original message. Finally, using a constant [iv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) is *not* recommended and may well render your system insecure in and of itself.

Comment: It looks like the base 64 encoded string is only 160-bit. But since the key is 256-bit, this is still considered 256-bit AES encryption?

Comment: @Wes It's a short message, but yes if the key is longer then the message that's possible. It's the key and the algorithm that determines the encryption type (**not** the message).

Comment: As for the constant IV, we are using a global encryption key that never changes (the application makes no use of sessions or logins) so IV doesn't seem to make sense for the application here. Since the algorithm requires one, instead of providing no IV I just provide a constant one.

Comment: @West Try encrypting a picture of a [penguin](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Tux_ecb.jpg). If it still looks like a penguin your cryptography is pointless (against an attacker).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That penguin story would be true if OP would use ECB mode. I don't think CBC with static IV is ECB.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I didn't say it was, but using a default IV makes it effectively the same.

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't think it does work this way. That penguin works, because in ECB every block is encrypted separately. Since CBC is *chained* even with a blank IV, the result will be noise. You won't be able to recognize the animal.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes, but you can follow the chain and render the image. I believe it was an exercise in Schneier's AC. But perhaps I misremember. I do recall that using a constant IV is bad news.

Comment: I guess a static IV would make it easier to find common prefixes in a collection of communications. I don't remember why this would be useful. It would be nice if you find that reference about the CBC animal.

Comment: What gets encrypted does not produce the penguin but maybe I'm doing it wrong. Basically the browser sends it base 64 encoded, backend encrypts it then base 64 encodes that. Then I base 64 decode that and try to view that as an image. And it appears to be something that can't even be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
key = sha.digest(key);
```

The following code creates a Hash of the input that is key. If we have some data "x" and "y" unless x=y
hash of "x" will never equal to hash of "y", this can be used to determine if original data is tampered because if it is it will produce a different hash.

```
key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32); // Use only first 256 bit
this.keyObj = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
```

In this case you are getting 32 bytes of the digest you have created and forming a secret key that is of size 256 bit as 8x32=256 
you are then using the cipher along with this key for encryption and decryption.

most of the Cipher's operate in blocks (this one does). They partition the text to be encrypted into fixed block size which is equal to key size and then apply XOR etc operation on the block to get the encrypted block . If the text size does not align with cipher block size then extra padding is appended to the text to align it to the fixed block size.

Comment: No, AES block size is 128-bit every time, but the key size may vary between 128-bit, 192-bit and 256-bit. What you probably mean is Rijndael, which also supports 256-bit block size.

Comment: You are right AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (128) "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html" . But i think the answer has cleared many doubts about the question.

Comment: In the above code you create the encryption key using "SHA-256", but then later down you associate that key with an "AES" encryption algorithm.  That is not correct, the algorithm being associated to that key should be "SHA-256" and not "AES".